# IFTTT Twitter to Twitter applet not posting "@" symbol

Tags: twitter, if-this-then-that

I want to make a retweet with IFTTT like it was done in the old days (since it's the only way you can retweet with IFTTT) by reposting the tweet and adding 
`RT: @user` in the message. But in the new tweet the "@" doesn't appear:

[image: WA108314 question example]

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IFTTT indeed prevents recipes from posting the @ sign. I believe this is a condition set by twitter to prevent IFTTT from spamming users.

The way around this is in fact using two separate IFTTT recipes:

1. **Twitter to Google Sheets:** use this recipe as **Trigger** to collect all the info you need like `username`, `text` etc... and assemble this info to compose the exact wording of the tweets you wish to send in a dedicated cell.
2. **Google Sheets to Twitter:** use this recipe as **Action**, to post the content of the dedicated cell to Twitter.

Posting from Google Sheets should resolve the problem.